# Null Check operator won't work on WebOperationContext.Current?.IncomingRequest

Tags: c#

It looked odd when I tried to add a null check operator on the following code

```
 WebOperationContext.Current?.IncomingRequest?.Headers[""];
```

This didn't catch the null and somehow Resharper recognized that question mark won't work and grayed it out.
But the following worked.

```
var httpIncomingRequest = WebOperationContext.Current?.IncomingRequest;
            var _ = httpIncomingRequest?.Headers[]
```

What is so special about IncomingRequest object that would stop us using null check operator?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a check in `Headers`. This proves my hypothesis. There isn't an exception if there is a check  in `Headers`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/OqcL9U

```
WebOperationContext.Current?.IncomingRequest?.Headers?[""];
```

Answer (score 1):

I decompiled the `WebOperationContext` class and found out that `IncomingRequest` property never returns null:

```
public IncomingWebRequestContext IncomingRequest
{
  get
  {
    return new IncomingWebRequestContext(this.operationContext);
  }
}
```

So it looks like R# is analyzing assembly bytecode and trying to check if question mark is redundant.